# Bounded variable: beta regression or switch to ratio?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, beta-distribution, beta-regression

My task is to study factors that influence the composition of labor force. The latter consists of two types of workers, full-time and part-time. My first approach was to run an OLS regression for the share of part-time workers, defined as

share = (number of part-time) / (part-time + full-time).

The issue is that this variable is bounded between 0 and 1, and I tried two alternative approaches. The first was to run beta regression (from betareg package), and the second was to move from share to ratio, defined as

ratio = number of part-time / number of full-time.

The ratio is not bounded. The results are similar, but the impact of one important variable is different. The coefficient for it is significant in either model, but positive in one and negative in the other. Is there any way to test which model, beta for share or OLS for ratio, is more consistent?

Comment: A Binomial GLM would likely be the most appropriate approach.  But since work forces tend to be large, this might be overkill.  Perhaps OLS is just fine: it's impossible to determine its applicability merely from the bounded nature of the `share` value.  The `ratio` approach is automatically suspect unless the numbers of full-time employees are consistently large and approximately equal, because otherwise it's likely to be strongly heteroscedastic.

Comment: Thank you! Could you recommend a way to check which approach for share, OLS or Binomial, is more appropriate? Also, would Beta-distribution work?

Comment: You choose partly based on the model.  If you are conceiving of the part-timers as randomly determined from all workers, the response distribution is Binomial.  A Beta regression would a little *ad hoc* (although it could work).